# Querying a joinned table in JPA Specifications

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to make a request to the endpoint `/users?numberOfBooksGreatherThan=5`, **i want the result to be a list of users with more than 5 books each.**
I use the specification API to implements it.

This is what i tried:

```java
public static Specification<User> userNumberOfBooksGreaterThan(Long number){
    return ((root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        Join<User, Book> userBooks = root.join("userBooksList");
        return criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(criteriaBuilder.count(userBooks.get("owner")), number);
    });
}
```

But i got this error

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE`

This is the SQL query executed behind (from logs):

```sql
select b1_0.user_id,b1_0.name from users b1_0 join books b2_0 on b1_0.user_id=b2_0.owner_id where count(b2_0.owner_id)>5
```

i saw some answer to a problem like this but it was just in SQL, saying that i should change `where` by `having` but i don't know how to do that with JPA Specification.

when i use the query below `(left outer join + group by + having)`, it returns the correct result, but i don't know  how to transform this query into a jpa specification.

```sql
select b1_0.user_id,b1_0.name, from users b1_0 left outer join books b2_0 on b1_0.user_id=b2_0.owner_id group by user_id having count(b2_0.owner_id)>=5;
```

This is the User entity definition

```java
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long userId;
    private String name;
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Book> userBooksList;
}
```

This is the Book entity definition

```java
@Entity(name = "books")
public class Book {
    @Id
    private Long bookId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ownerId",referencedColumnName = "userId",nullable = false)
    private User owner;
    private Float price;
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: The SQL you are showing doesn't seem correct - you have grouping on id but are selecting the name and id - it should fail. Try a subselect instead: (JPQL)"select user from User user where (select count (b) from Books b where b.owner=user) > :number". You should be able to turn the subquery into a predicate https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-subquery-criteriaquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the SQL statement you are trying to get:

```
select b1_0.user_id, b1_0.name from users b1_0 
 left outer join books b2_0 on b1_0.user_id=b2_0.owner_id 
group by user_id 
having count(b2_0.owner_id)>=5;
```

is syntactically correct, at least for `Oracle` it is not. However there are following options:

1. Having/group by

```
(root, cq, cb) -> {
   Join<User, Book> books = root.join("userBooksList");
   cq.having(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(cb.count(books), number));
   cq.groupBy(root);
   return cb.and();
}
```

or

```
(root, cq, cb) -> {
   Root<Book> bookRoot = cq.from(Book.class);
   cq.having(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(cb.count(bookRoot), number));
   cq.groupBy(root);
   return cb.equal(bookRoot.get("owner"), root);
}
```

2. correlated subquery (this one produces syntactically correct SQL statement)

```
(root, cq, cb) -> {
   Subquery<Long> subq = cq.subquery(Long.class);
   Root<Book> bookRoot = subq.from(Book.class);
   subq.where(cb.equal(bookRoot.get("owner"), subq.correlate(root)));
   return cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(subq.select(cb.count(bookRoot)), number);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i used the first  option. When i tried to use it with lessThan, it was ignoring those who have no books. then i added JoinType.LEFT to join(). it worked. Where can i learn to use JPA please

Comment: @JotterKain if you just started your learning curve, I would suggest to learn `JPQL` first, it is very similar to `SQL` and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL , for example, does not look bad. Criteria API (what you are actually trying to use) is high-level abstraction and it's purpose is to translate that ugly java code into `JPQL`, IMO if you know what you what to get in `JPQL` it is much simpler to write corresponding Criteria API code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo (Should be greaterThan instead of greatherThan).

EDIT: You should reverse the query, instead of Join<Book,User> it should be Join<User,Book>. owner is a field of User entity, not reachable through Book.

```
public static Specification<User> userNumberOfBooksGreaterThan(Long number) {
return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
    Join<User, Book> userBooks = root.join("userBooksList");
    return criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(criteriaBuilder.count(userBooks), number);
};}
```

Changing the comparison in the criteriaBuilder will give you the correct count of books for each user.

Greetings!

Comment: yes, i just edited the question. thank you. but it doesn't solve the actual problem. i write de code in the answer manually since it is just a simple example.

Comment: Yes you are right again. This is another mistake from me but it doesn’t solves the problem